# Cannot create trigger in mysql because of #1193 error code

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to create a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_klienci
BEFORE INSERT ON `klienci`
FOR EACH ROW
SET `id` = uuid()
```

Unfortunately I got:

```
#1193 - Unknown system variable 'id'
```

I am completely sure that a column `id` exists and I have no typo.

Any ideas?

Have a good day,
Przemek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the new row updated with the UUID, so you just need to tell the trigger where to find the `id` value you want updated;

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_klienci
BEFORE INSERT ON `klienci`
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.`id` = uuid();
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4acb/1).